# How can I solve the error in TRANSIESTA calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta, electronic-transport

Recently, I've been trying to calculate the transmission coefficients for the molecular junction (Au lattice - molecule - Au lattice) using SIESTA, TRANSIESTA, and TBtrans.
As you know, the procedure for calculating the transmission functions based on non-equilibrium green's function is like below.
(1) SIESTA calculation for the electrode to obtain .TSHS file
(2) TRANSIESTA calculation for the junction to get .TSHS file
(3) Using the results of (1) and (2), TBtrans calculation

I finished the step (1) and it's time to proceed step (2) but the error message is occurred at this time.
The error message is like below.

```
 <sparsity:./elec_au_100.TSHS
 nrows_g=1080 nrows=1080 sparsity=2.3075 nnzs=2691504, refcount: 3>
 <sparsity:(TM [--,--, 0] of: ./elec_au_100.TSHS)
 nrows_g=1080 nrows=1080 sparsity=1.1888 nnzs=1386576, refcount: 3>
 <sparsity:(TM [--,--,-1] of: ./elec_au_100.TSHS)
 nrows_g=1080 nrows=1080 sparsity=.5339 nnzs=622764, refcount: 3>
 Left principal cell is extending out with 29700 elements:
 Atom 5 connects with atom 55
 Orbital 74 connects with orbital 824
 Hamiltonian value: |H(74,49424)|@R=-2 =  0.738E-02 eV
 Overlap          :  S(74,49424)|@R=-2 = -0.413E-04
```

I found the question on this community ([TBT Transiesta Calculation error](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/tbt-transiesta-calculation-error)) similar to my case and it says that the interactions between the supercells induce these kinds of errors.
So the solution is adding more layers in the electrode calculations.
However, as you can see in the attached fdf file in the bottom, the each electrode is composed of 6 gold layers(3X6X6) and I defined the electrode as 4 gold layers so it looks enough.
The strange point is that when I used the half size in y-direction(3X3X6) as the electrode, the calculations worked well so I could get the transmission coefficients.
Can you suggest a solution to solve this problem?

Your comments surely helpful for advancing my research.
Thank you in advance. :)

Sincerely,
Jonghwan Lee

```
SolutionMethod        Transiesta

SystemName  Au 100 with gold chain
SystemLabel au_100



==================================================
==================================================
# SPECIES AND BASIS

# Number of species 
NumberOfSpecies 4
%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
 1 79 Au
 2 16 S
 3 6 C
 4 1 H
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel

PAO.BasisSize    DZP
PAO.EnergyShift  0.005 Ry
XC.functional   GGA
XC.authors      PBE


==================================================
==================================================
# K-points

%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
 1    0    0    0.0
 0    1    0    0.0
 0    0    1    0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack



==================================================
==================================================
# Structure
NumberOfAtoms 231
LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
     8.651160000      0.000000000      0.000000000 
     0.000000000      17.30232000      0.000000000 
     0.000000000      0.000000000     37.625600000
%endblock LatticeVectors
AtomicCoordinatesFormat  Ang
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000 1 #   1: Au
  2.88370000  0.00000000  0.00000000 1 #   2: Au
  5.76740000  0.00000000  0.00000000 1 #   3: Au
  0.00000000  2.88370000  0.00000000 1 #   4: Au
  2.88370000  2.88370000  0.00000000 1 #   5: Au
  5.76740000  2.88370000  0.00000000 1 #   6: Au
  0.00000000  5.76740000  0.00000000 1 #   7: Au
  2.88370000  5.76740000  0.00000000 1 #   8: Au
  5.76740000  5.76740000  0.00000000 1 #   9: Au
  0.00000000  8.65110000  0.00000000 1 #  10: Au
  2.88370000  8.65110000  0.00000000 1 #  11: Au
  5.76740000  8.65110000  0.00000000 1 #  12: Au
  0.00000000 11.53480000  0.00000000 1 #  13: Au
  2.88370000 11.53480000  0.00000000 1 #  14: Au
  5.76740000 11.53480000  0.00000000 1 #  15: Au
  0.00000000 14.41850000  0.00000000 1 #  16: Au
  2.88370000 14.41850000  0.00000000 1 #  17: Au
  5.76740000 14.41850000  0.00000000 1 #  18: Au
  1.44190000  1.44190000  2.03910000 1 #  19: Au
  4.32560000  1.44190000  2.03910000 1 #  20: Au
  7.20930000  1.44190000  2.03910000 1 #  21: Au
  1.44190000  4.32560000  2.03910000 1 #  22: Au
  4.32560000  4.32560000  2.03910000 1 #  23: Au
  7.20930000  4.32560000  2.03910000 1 #  24: Au
  1.44190000  7.20930000  2.03910000 1 #  25: Au
  4.32560000  7.20930000  2.03910000 1 #  26: Au
  7.20930000  7.20930000  2.03910000 1 #  27: Au
  1.44190000 10.09300000  2.03910000 1 #  28: Au
  4.32560000 10.09300000  2.03910000 1 #  29: Au
  7.20930000 10.09300000  2.03910000 1 #  30: Au
  1.44190000 12.97670000  2.03910000 1 #  31: Au
  4.32560000 12.97670000  2.03910000 1 #  32: Au
  7.20930000 12.97670000  2.03910000 1 #  33: Au
  1.44190000 15.86040000  2.03910000 1 #  34: Au
  4.32560000 15.86040000  2.03910000 1 #  35: Au
  7.20930000 15.86040000  2.03910000 1 #  36: Au
  0.00000000  0.00000000  4.07820000 1 #  37: Au
  2.88370000  0.00000000  4.07820000 1 #  38: Au
  5.76740000  0.00000000  4.07820000 1 #  39: Au
  0.00000000  2.88370000  4.07820000 1 #  40: Au
  2.88370000  2.88370000  4.07820000 1 #  41: Au
  5.76740000  2.88370000  4.07820000 1 #  42: Au
  0.00000000  5.76740000  4.07820000 1 #  43: Au
  2.88370000  5.76740000  4.07820000 1 #  44: Au
  5.76740000  5.76740000  4.07820000 1 #  45: Au
  0.00000000  8.65110000  4.07820000 1 #  46: Au
  2.88370000  8.65110000  4.07820000 1 #  47: Au
  5.76740000  8.65110000  4.07820000 1 #  48: Au
  0.00000000 11.53480000  4.07820000 1 #  49: Au
  2.88370000 11.53480000  4.07820000 1 #  50: Au
  5.76740000 11.53480000  4.07820000 1 #  51: Au
  0.00000000 14.41850000  4.07820000 1 #  52: Au
  2.88370000 14.41850000  4.07820000 1 #  53: Au
  5.76740000 14.41850000  4.07820000 1 #  54: Au
  1.44190000  1.44190000  6.11730000 1 #  55: Au
  4.32560000  1.44190000  6.11730000 1 #  56: Au
  7.20930000  1.44190000  6.11730000 1 #  57: Au
  1.44190000  4.32560000  6.11730000 1 #  58: Au
  4.32560000  4.32560000  6.11730000 1 #  59: Au
  7.20930000  4.32560000  6.11730000 1 #  60: Au
  1.44190000  7.20930000  6.11730000 1 #  61: Au
  4.32560000  7.20930000  6.11730000 1 #  62: Au
  7.20930000  7.20930000  6.11730000 1 #  63: Au
  1.44190000 10.09300000  6.11730000 1 #  64: Au
  4.32560000 10.09300000  6.11730000 1 #  65: Au
  7.20930000 10.09300000  6.11730000 1 #  66: Au
  1.44190000 12.97670000  6.11730000 1 #  67: Au
  4.32560000 12.97670000  6.11730000 1 #  68: Au
  7.20930000 12.97670000  6.11730000 1 #  69: Au
  1.44190000 15.86040000  6.11730000 1 #  70: Au
  4.32560000 15.86040000  6.11730000 1 #  71: Au
  7.20930000 15.86040000  6.11730000 1 #  72: Au
  0.00000000  0.00000000  8.15640000 1 #  73: Au
  2.88370000  0.00000000  8.15640000 1 #  74: Au
  5.76740000  0.00000000  8.15640000 1 #  75: Au
  0.00000000  2.88370000  8.15640000 1 #  76: Au
  2.88370000  2.88370000  8.15640000 1 #  77: Au
  5.76740000  2.88370000  8.15640000 1 #  78: Au
  0.00000000  5.76740000  8.15640000 1 #  79: Au
  2.88370000  5.76740000  8.15640000 1 #  80: Au
  5.76740000  5.76740000  8.15640000 1 #  81: Au
  0.00000000  8.65110000  8.15640000 1 #  82: Au
  2.88370000  8.65110000  8.15640000 1 #  83: Au
  5.76740000  8.65110000  8.15640000 1 #  84: Au
  0.00000000 11.53480000  8.15640000 1 #  85: Au
  2.88370000 11.53480000  8.15640000 1 #  86: Au
  5.76740000 11.53480000  8.15640000 1 #  87: Au
  0.00000000 14.41850000  8.15640000 1 #  88: Au
  2.88370000 14.41850000  8.15640000 1 #  89: Au
  5.76740000 14.41850000  8.15640000 1 #  90: Au
  1.44190000  1.44190000 10.19550000 1 #  91: Au
  4.32560000  1.44190000 10.19550000 1 #  92: Au
  7.20930000  1.44190000 10.19550000 1 #  93: Au
  1.44190000  4.32560000 10.19550000 1 #  94: Au
  4.32560000  4.32560000 10.19550000 1 #  95: Au
  7.20930000  4.32560000 10.19550000 1 #  96: Au
  1.44190000  7.20930000 10.19550000 1 #  97: Au
  4.32560000  7.20930000 10.19550000 1 #  98: Au
  7.20930000  7.20930000 10.19550000 1 #  99: Au
  1.44190000 10.09300000 10.19550000 1 # 100: Au
  4.32560000 10.09300000 10.19550000 1 # 101: Au
  7.20930000 10.09300000 10.19550000 1 # 102: Au
  1.44190000 12.97670000 10.19550000 1 # 103: Au
  4.32560000 12.97670000 10.19550000 1 # 104: Au
  7.20930000 12.97670000 10.19550000 1 # 105: Au
  1.44190000 15.86040000 10.19550000 1 # 106: Au
  4.32560000 15.86040000 10.19550000 1 # 107: Au
  7.20930000 15.86040000 10.19550000 1 # 108: Au
  4.32560000  8.96360000 13.19515000 2 # 109: S
  4.32560000  8.11530000 14.74325000 3 # 110: C
  4.17170000  6.36840000 14.80375000 2 # 111: S
  4.34700000  8.67750000 15.97895000 3 # 112: C
  4.16920000  6.42580000 16.52505000 3 # 113: C
  4.25980000  7.70860000 17.01965000 3 # 114: C
  4.42450000  9.74510000 16.12965000 4 # 115: H
  4.07580000  5.18740000 17.74865000 2 # 116: S
  4.25130000  7.71510000 18.45715000 3 # 117: C
  4.15480000  6.43670000 18.96225000 3 # 118: C
  4.32630000  8.69320000 19.49015000 3 # 119: C
  4.13700000  6.39480000 20.68375000 2 # 120: S
  4.29010000  8.14220000 20.73045000 3 # 121: C
  4.40550000  9.75940000 19.33095000 4 # 122: H
  4.27110000  9.00430000 22.27075000 2 # 123: S
  2.88370000  0.00000000 25.27040000 1 # 124: Au
  5.76740000  0.00000000 25.27040000 1 # 125: Au
  0.00000000  2.88370000 25.27040000 1 # 126: Au
  2.88370000  2.88370000 25.27040000 1 # 127: Au
  5.76740000  2.88370000 25.27040000 1 # 128: Au
  0.00000000  5.76740000 25.27040000 1 # 129: Au
  2.88370000  5.76740000 25.27040000 1 # 130: Au
  5.76740000  5.76740000 25.27040000 1 # 131: Au
  0.00000000  8.65110000 25.27040000 1 # 132: Au
  2.88370000  8.65110000 25.27040000 1 # 133: Au
  5.76740000  8.65110000 25.27040000 1 # 134: Au
  0.00000000 11.53480000 25.27040000 1 # 135: Au
  2.88370000 11.53480000 25.27040000 1 # 136: Au
  5.76740000 11.53480000 25.27040000 1 # 137: Au
  0.00000000 14.41850000 25.27040000 1 # 138: Au
  2.88370000 14.41850000 25.27040000 1 # 139: Au
  5.76740000 14.41850000 25.27040000 1 # 140: Au
  0.00000000  0.00000000 25.27040000 1 # 141: Au
  1.44190000  1.44190000 27.30950000 1 # 142: Au
  4.32560000  1.44190000 27.30950000 1 # 143: Au
  7.20930000  1.44190000 27.30950000 1 # 144: Au
  1.44190000  4.32560000 27.30950000 1 # 145: Au
  4.32560000  4.32560000 27.30950000 1 # 146: Au
  7.20930000  4.32560000 27.30950000 1 # 147: Au
  1.44190000  7.20930000 27.30950000 1 # 148: Au
  4.32560000  7.20930000 27.30950000 1 # 149: Au
  7.20930000  7.20930000 27.30950000 1 # 150: Au
  1.44190000 10.09300000 27.30950000 1 # 151: Au
  4.32560000 10.09300000 27.30950000 1 # 152: Au
  7.20930000 10.09300000 27.30950000 1 # 153: Au
  1.44190000 12.97670000 27.30950000 1 # 154: Au
  4.32560000 12.97670000 27.30950000 1 # 155: Au
  7.20930000 12.97670000 27.30950000 1 # 156: Au
  1.44190000 15.86040000 27.30950000 1 # 157: Au
  4.32560000 15.86040000 27.30950000 1 # 158: Au
  7.20930000 15.86040000 27.30950000 1 # 159: Au
  0.00000000  0.00000000 29.34860000 1 # 160: Au
  2.88370000  0.00000000 29.34860000 1 # 161: Au
  5.76740000  0.00000000 29.34860000 1 # 162: Au
  0.00000000  2.88370000 29.34860000 1 # 163: Au
  2.88370000  2.88370000 29.34860000 1 # 164: Au
  5.76740000  2.88370000 29.34860000 1 # 165: Au
  0.00000000  5.76740000 29.34860000 1 # 166: Au
  2.88370000  5.76740000 29.34860000 1 # 167: Au
  5.76740000  5.76740000 29.34860000 1 # 168: Au
  0.00000000  8.65110000 29.34860000 1 # 169: Au
  2.88370000  8.65110000 29.34860000 1 # 170: Au
  5.76740000  8.65110000 29.34860000 1 # 171: Au
  0.00000000 11.53480000 29.34860000 1 # 172: Au
  2.88370000 11.53480000 29.34860000 1 # 173: Au
  5.76740000 11.53480000 29.34860000 1 # 174: Au
  0.00000000 14.41850000 29.34860000 1 # 175: Au
  2.88370000 14.41850000 29.34860000 1 # 176: Au
  5.76740000 14.41850000 29.34860000 1 # 177: Au
  1.44190000  1.44190000 31.38770000 1 # 178: Au
  4.32560000  1.44190000 31.38770000 1 # 179: Au
  7.20930000  1.44190000 31.38770000 1 # 180: Au
  1.44190000  4.32560000 31.38770000 1 # 181: Au
  4.32560000  4.32560000 31.38770000 1 # 182: Au
  7.20930000  4.32560000 31.38770000 1 # 183: Au
  1.44190000  7.20930000 31.38770000 1 # 184: Au
  4.32560000  7.20930000 31.38770000 1 # 185: Au
  7.20930000  7.20930000 31.38770000 1 # 186: Au
  1.44190000 10.09300000 31.38770000 1 # 187: Au
  4.32560000 10.09300000 31.38770000 1 # 188: Au
  7.20930000 10.09300000 31.38770000 1 # 189: Au
  1.44190000 12.97670000 31.38770000 1 # 190: Au
  4.32560000 12.97670000 31.38770000 1 # 191: Au
  7.20930000 12.97670000 31.38770000 1 # 192: Au
  1.44190000 15.86040000 31.38770000 1 # 193: Au
  4.32560000 15.86040000 31.38770000 1 # 194: Au
  7.20930000 15.86040000 31.38770000 1 # 195: Au
  0.00000000  0.00000000 33.42680000 1 # 196: Au
  2.88370000  0.00000000 33.42680000 1 # 197: Au
  5.76740000  0.00000000 33.42680000 1 # 198: Au
  0.00000000  2.88370000 33.42680000 1 # 199: Au
  2.88370000  2.88370000 33.42680000 1 # 200: Au
  5.76740000  2.88370000 33.42680000 1 # 201: Au
  0.00000000  5.76740000 33.42680000 1 # 202: Au
  2.88370000  5.76740000 33.42680000 1 # 203: Au
  5.76740000  5.76740000 33.42680000 1 # 204: Au
  0.00000000  8.65110000 33.42680000 1 # 205: Au
  2.88370000  8.65110000 33.42680000 1 # 206: Au
  5.76740000  8.65110000 33.42680000 1 # 207: Au
  0.00000000 11.53480000 33.42680000 1 # 208: Au
  2.88370000 11.53480000 33.42680000 1 # 209: Au
  5.76740000 11.53480000 33.42680000 1 # 210: Au
  0.00000000 14.41850000 33.42680000 1 # 211: Au
  2.88370000 14.41850000 33.42680000 1 # 212: Au
  5.76740000 14.41850000 33.42680000 1 # 213: Au
  1.44190000  1.44190000 35.46590000 1 # 214: Au
  4.32560000  1.44190000 35.46590000 1 # 215: Au
  7.20930000  1.44190000 35.46590000 1 # 216: Au
  1.44190000  4.32560000 35.46590000 1 # 217: Au
  4.32560000  4.32560000 35.46590000 1 # 218: Au
  7.20930000  4.32560000 35.46590000 1 # 219: Au
  1.44190000  7.20930000 35.46590000 1 # 220: Au
  4.32560000  7.20930000 35.46590000 1 # 221: Au
  7.20930000  7.20930000 35.46590000 1 # 222: Au
  1.44190000 10.09300000 35.46590000 1 # 223: Au
  4.32560000 10.09300000 35.46590000 1 # 224: Au
  7.20930000 10.09300000 35.46590000 1 # 225: Au
  1.44190000 12.97670000 35.46590000 1 # 226: Au
  4.32560000 12.97670000 35.46590000 1 # 227: Au
  7.20930000 12.97670000 35.46590000 1 # 228: Au
  1.44190000 15.86040000 35.46590000 1 # 229: Au
  4.32560000 15.86040000 35.46590000 1 # 230: Au
  7.20930000 15.86040000 35.46590000 1 # 231: Au
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies


==================================================
==================================================
# SCF variables

DM.MixSCF1   T
MaxSCFIterations      1000           # Maximum number of SCF iter
DM.MixingWeight       0.02          # New DM amount for next SCF cycle
DM.Tolerance          1.d-4         # Tolerance in maximum difference
DM.UseSaveDM          true          # to use continuation files
DM.NumberPulay        8
MeshCutoff            50. Ry
TS.MixH               yes

==================================================
==================================================
# MD variables

MD.FinalTimeStep 1
MD.TypeOfRun CG
MD.NumCGsteps     000
MD.UseSaveXV      .true.

==================================================
==================================================
# Output variables

WriteMullikenPop                1
WriteBands                      .false.
SaveRho                         .false.
SaveDeltaRho                    .false.
SaveHS                          .false.
SaveElectrostaticPotential      True 
SaveTotalPotential              no
WriteCoorXmol                   .true.
WriteMDXmol                     .true.
WriteMDhistory                  .false.
WriteEigenvalues                yes
TS.HS.Save          True



==================================================
==================================================

# Bias voltage
TS.Voltage 0.0 eV
%block TS.ChemPots
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.ChemPots

%block TS.ChemPot.Left
  mu V/2
  contour.eq
    begin
      c-Left
      t-Left
    end
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Left
%block TS.ChemPot.Right
  mu -V/2
  contour.eq
    begin
      c-Right
      t-Right
    end
%endblock TS.ChemPot.Right

TS.Elecs.Bulk true
TS.Elecs.DM.Update none
TS.Elecs.GF.ReUse false
%block TS.Elecs
  Left
  Right
%endblock TS.Elecs

%block TS.Elec.Left
  TSHS ./elec_au_100.TSHS
  chem-pot Left
  semi-inf-dir -a3
  elec-pos begin 1
  used-atoms 72
%endblock TS.Elec.Left

%block TS.Elec.Right
  TSHS ./elec_au_100.TSHS
  chem-pot Right
  semi-inf-dir +a3
  elec-pos end -1
  used-atoms 72
%endblock TS.Elec.Right

TS.Contours.Eq.Pole 2.5 eV
%block TS.Contour.c-Left
  part circle
   from   -40.00000 eV + V/2 to -10. kT + V/2
    points 30
     method g-legendre
%endblock TS.Contour.c-Left
%block TS.Contour.t-Left
  part tail
   from prev to inf
    points 10
     method g-fermi
%endblock TS.Contour.t-Left
%block TS.Contour.c-Right
  part circle
   from   -40.00000 eV - V/2 to -10. kT - V/2
    points 30
     method g-legendre
%endblock TS.Contour.c-Right
%block TS.Contour.t-Right
  part tail
   from prev to inf
    points 10
     method g-fermi
%endblock TS.Contour.t-Right

TS.Contours.nEq.Eta 0.0001 eV
%block TS.Contours.nEq
  neq
%endblock TS.Contours.nEq
%block TS.Contour.nEq.neq
  part line
   from -|V|/2 - 5 kT to |V|/2 + 5 kT
    delta 0.01 eV
     method mid-rule
%endblock TS.Contour.nEq.neq
```

Comment: the matter-modelling framework is based on 1 question questions, your Q has multiple, try and concentrate what your question is, also the title should be a bit more informative with respect to what the question is about.

Comment: @nickpapior Ok, I just edited my question now.

Answer (score 3):

The only restriction for interaction is that of the interaction along the semi-infinite direction. The transverse directions can be *any* size you wish. However, it would always be beneficial to reduce the transverse directions such that one can utilise Bloch's theorem. This will greatly improve the throughput!

Otherwise this question is completely equivalent to the answer linked: [TBtrans/Transiesta, error: "connectivity is not perfect"](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/tbt-transiesta-calculation-error)